# Insert value into second table after checking value from first table

Tags: mysql

```
**FIRST TABLE**
classroom_id | classroom_name | classroom_unique_code |

**SECOND TABLE**
robot_id | robot_mac_address | classroom_id |
```

I want to store the value of classroom id from classroom table to robot table according to the classroom_unique_code as robot will be assigned to that classroom. 
Every classroom has a random generated unique code.

Comment: You need to show sample data and also tell us what the _relation_ is between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
INSERT INTO robots(robot_id, robot_mac_address, classroom_id) 
      SELECT 'robot id value', 'robot mac address', (SELECT classroom_id FROM classroom WHERE classroom_unique_code = 'the classroom unique id')
```

Of course you need to adapt `'robot id value'`, `'robot mac address'` and `'the classrooms unique id'` to your actual datatypes and values.